# BigInteger::intValueExact() - what's the point?

Tags: java, biginteger

I noticed that the class `BigInteger` received a new method in Java 8: `intValueExact()`.

My question is: why?

```
BigInteger bigInt = ... ;

bigInt.intValueExact();
```

`BigInteger` already had `intValue()`. The `intValueExact()` is meant to throw an error when your `BigInteger` does not hold an exact `int` value, but my question is: how could it be possible to give a `BigInteger` a value that will not equate to an exact `int` ? Can someone provide an example of when this method would throw an `ArithmeticException` ??

Comment: What if the `BigInteger` is too big to fit in an `int`?

Comment: `BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).add(BigInteger.ONE)` BOOM

Comment: Here's a question. If a `BigInteger` can't hold a value larger than an `int`, what would be the point _of_ `BigInteger`?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, `BigInteger` can hold a value larger than `int`. @yshavit's comment was an example scenario of when calling `intValueExact()` would throw an error, which is what the original question asked for.

Comment: @ryvanage I saw his comment. I was not addressing the OP's question, but rather, asking a question to make the OP _think_.

Comment: I am thinking, @ColeJohnson. It was a dumb question. I see that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
new BigInteger("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000").intValueExact()
```

If the `BigInteger` is too big an integer to fit into an `int`, the exception is thrown.

Comment: You call that a big number? Ha! `new BigInteger("BusyBeaver(9)")`, now [_that's_](http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/bignumbers.html) a big number!

Comment: @yshavit Except for the nasty little issue that the number is not computable and we don't know the exact value of BusyBeaver(9), for any of the numerous slightly different definitions of `BusyBeaver`. Luckily, just interpreting the string's 13 code units as a 26 bytes integer yields an integer far beyond the range of `int`. And it's still larger than the number in this answer :-)

Comment: @yshavit Don't you mean you need to `import ChuckNorris;`? ;)

Answer (score 14):

The [`intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue--) method will only keep the lowest 32 bits that will fit in an `int`, discarding information if necessary.

> Converts this BigInteger to an int. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

The [`intValueExact()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValueExact--) method will throw an exception in this case rather than give you a different value.

> Converts this BigInteger to an int, checking for lost information. If the value of this BigInteger is out of the range of the int type, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValueExact--):

> Converts this BigInteger to an int, checking for lost information. If the value of this BigInteger is out of the range of the int type, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

So quite simply if the value of the `BigInteger` is greater than 2^31 - 1 then an `ArithmeticException` is thrown.